# Most suitable clustering method for a dataset containing 10 dimension numerical arrays

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a data set (~4k samples) of the following structure:

sample type: string  - very general
sample sub type:
 string
sample model number: number - may be None
signature: number array[10]
sampleID: string - unique id

I want to cluster the samples based on the "signature" (I have a function that measures "distance" between one signature to another).
 So that when I'll encounter a new signature I'll be able to tell to which type/sub type the sample belongs to.
Which algorithm should I use?

P.S. (I am using python and scikit-learn), I also need to somehow visualize the results.

Comment: Which algorithm to use depends on the properties of your data. Your first stop should certainly be http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a distance function, and yoour data set is tiny, just use HAC, the grandfather of all clustering algorithms.